# UzysSlideMenu: how to use several view controllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I just came across a slide-in menu I really like: https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysSlideMenu

I would like to use this menu for an application that uses several view controllers (UIViewControllers and UINavigationControllers).

In Xcode, I created a single view application and made the view controller (MenuViewController) show the menu, like the creator did in his example project. I added more view controllers to the storyboard and connected them via segues to the MenuViewController. Upon selecting a menu item, these segues are triggered and the selected view is shown - so far so good.

But now, I run into the following problem:

All my view controllers are shown in full screen. That means that VCs that get segue'd in the viewport don't show the menu, because it's just not implemented there. I could put the menu in every VC, but that doesn't seem to be the right way to do it (even if I use some custom delegate method that every controller calls, like putMenuInViewController:(UIViewController *)target). I think I need something like a global singleton for the menu and make it appear in every view controller, but I have absolutely no idea on how to it or what to google for.

Any points into the right direction are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement one root view controller with this menu as singleton, and add other view controller as child view controller to it.

I wrote a post about it, you can find it here:http://antrix1989.blogspot.com/2013/09/uiviewcontroller-as-singleton.html